# Dependent projects being built in Hudson -- how to stop this?

Tags: svn, triggers, hudson, build-automation, jenkins

I have a use case where I need to run a Hudson build once for a release to trigger a plugin that we don't want run at any other time and which we don't want to place inside the pom (see: [Is it possible to replace the entire Repository Url with a parameterized string in Hudson/Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750270/is-it-possible-to-replace-the-entire-repository-url-with-a-parameterized-string-i)).

Basically, I take the svn release url for the project and execute a build on it. However, it triggers dependent builds. This, despite the fact that the following options are not checked:

- Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency
- is built Build after other projects
- are built Build other projects

I don't understand why this association is occurring (especially since it's a release). I especially don't understand why this occurs for a project that has no dependencies on other projects being built in hudson (however, other projects are dependent on it).

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or how I can stop Hudson from triggering any other builds when I build this release?

Answer (score 0):

Do any of the dependent jobs have the "Build when a URL's content changes" options enabled ?

If your parent job is publishing artifacts to the location the dependent jobs are watching, that would be enough to trigger the dependent builds.